# Unable to access remote files through filezilla on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, filezilla

Previously it was working. After upgrading my Operating System to Ubuntu 14.04, I can't able to access my website files through filezilla. Here is the response that i got

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.xxxx.com
Status: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 4 of 150 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 05:31. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 5 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Screenshot attached here for your reference.

[image]

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys. I'm moving this question to Super User since it's off-topic here as per [Martin Prikry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl)l suggestion